# CouchDB on Virtual Server

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, virtualization, virtual-server

I'm writing a web application which basically searches your Twitter timeline for links. I used to use MongoDB for saving tweets and information, which worked fine on my dev system, but crashed after some time on a virtual server during tests. I know that MongoDB has some problems with virtualization - it even warns about this on startup.

I wonder, if CouchDB has the same problems. Do you have any experience with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB has no known problems with virtualization. Many people use CouchDB in production on virtual servers.